# AWS Kinesis Enhanced fan-out Java example

Tags: java, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kcl

I have an application that consumes records from Kinesis streams and processes them further but the performance is quite low, So now I am planning to migrate to the Kinesis Enhanced fan-out consumer using KCL 2.x to improve its performance. As the Aws Kinesis docs for the enhanced fan-out is quite confusing, can someone help me with an example of how I can implement this consumer feature in my Java application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very detailed example of a KCL 2.x consumer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/building-enhanced-consumers-kcl-java.html

The most important parts are:

- `SampleRecordProcessor` - implementation of the ShardRecordProcessor interface where the consumer processing logic lives.
- `SampleRecordProcessorFactory`
- `Scheduler` config:

```java
Scheduler scheduler = new Scheduler(
                configsBuilder.checkpointConfig(),
                configsBuilder.coordinatorConfig(),
                configsBuilder.leaseManagementConfig(),
                configsBuilder.lifecycleConfig(),
                configsBuilder.metricsConfig(),
                configsBuilder.processorConfig(),
                configsBuilder.retrievalConfig()
        );
```

The important part above is that the default retrievalConfig() is specified, which configures Enhanced fan-out consumer under the hood. The explicit way is the following:

```java
Scheduler scheduler = new Scheduler(
                configsBuilder.checkpointConfig(),
                configsBuilder.coordinatorConfig(),
                configsBuilder.leaseManagementConfig(),
                configsBuilder.lifecycleConfig(),
                configsBuilder.metricsConfig(),
                configsBuilder.processorConfig(),
                configsBuilder.retrievalConfig()
                       .retrievalSpecificConfig(
                           new FanOutConfig(kinesisClient)
                             .streamName(streamName)
                             .applicationName(appName)
                           )
                       .maxListShardsRetryAttempts(maxListShardsRetryAttempts)
                       .initialPositionInStreamExtended(
       InitialPositionInStreamExtended.newInitialPosition(initialPositionInStream)
                 )
        );
```